# Android Studio : Unable to recreate missing debug keystore

Tags: android-studio

I'm sorry if this question is duplicate, but I have spent a few days finding solution to the problem and couldn't find one, also I can't comment in the existing question so I decided to ask a new one.
When I try to run my app in Android Studio I have this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:validateDebugSigning'.
> Unable to recreate missing debug keystore.
```

As far as I know, the keystore file is located in the folder (user)/.android (I'm using Windows 8.1) but there IS a keystore file in this folder.
**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**
- I deleted the old keystore file and tried to create a new one by running the app in Android Stuidio but like the error said, it couldn't create keystore file. 
- I managed to create a new keystore file by running the app in Eclipse, this is the ddms.cfg file:

```
#Thu Jul 16 17:18:42 ICT 2015
pingOptIn=true
adtUsed=true
pingTime.eclipse=1437041922450
pingTime.adt=1437041922448
pingId=-2893797175409321994
```

I also checked the permission of the .android folder, all permissions are allowed.
Still, I have the same error when I try to run the app.
Hope someone can help me.
(I know there already is a question with the same title but I couldn't understand the answer, also I can't comment to ask)

Answer (score 2):

you have to check the permission of .android file by the following commands..

```
$cd ~
$ls -la
```

then you will see the file ".android", its permission level.. which user its permitted to if there are more than one users. if such a case then give sudo permission by the required user.. In my case

```
sudo chmod 777 -R .android
```

Comment: It's Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You will give `sudo chmod -R 777` in `.android`, see that is a directory not visible located in `~/`.

Comment: 1. verify that all directory are in ~./bashrc.

export PATH=${PATH}:~/Android/Sdk/tools/
export PATH=${PATH}:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/
export PATH=${PATH}:~/Android/Sdk/platforms/
export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/android/plugins/android-ndk/
export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/android/plugins/android/lib/

2. that the sdk of android are update
3. Directory /home/youuser/.android that is not visible also are with permit
could not write to the debug file, that file automatically creates android, this is a permissions issue, even have the 755 permission does not work, it should be 777